# Inserting the records in a table

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm new to C#

I'm working on the milk collection center software project.

I have prepared a form in which I'm entering the name and information of the customers.

I want to insert the entered information in to the table which I have created in MS Access.

I'm unable to insert the records.

---

Say I have the following:

```
public class Record
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public bool Status { get; set; }
   public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Given a List records, how do I transform it into a DataSet as follows:

```
ID Status Message
1  true   "message" 
2  false  "message2" 
3  true   "message3" 
...
```

At the moment the only thing I can think of is as follows:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet
ds.Tables.Add();
ds.Tables[0].Add("ID", typeof(int));    
ds.Tables[0].Add("Status", typeof(bool));
ds.Tables[0].Add("Message", typeof(string));

foreach(Record record in records)
{
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(record.ID, record.Status, record.Message);
}
```

---

So guys, please help me, tell me how can I do this insertion.

Comment: Show the code you have done so far .. will be easier to know what you missed

Comment: This is not a question, this is a request to write all the code for you. This is not rentacoder.com. Post the code you tried please...

Comment: public class Record
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public bool Status { get; set; }
   public string Message { get; set; }
}

Comment: Given a List records, how do I transform it into a DataSet as follows:ID Status Message
1  true   "message" 
2  false  "message2" 
3  true   "message3" 
...

Comment: At the moment the only thing I can think of is as follows:         DataSet ds = new DataSet
ds.Tables.Add();
ds.Tables[0].Add("ID", typeof(int));    
ds.Tables[0].Add("Status", typeof(bool));
ds.Tables[0].Add("Message", typeof(string));

foreach(Record record in records)
{
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(record.ID, record.Status, record.Message);
}

Comment: @Rockstar: edit your question to add the code in.

Comment: also, cut down on the number of `.` you use when writing :D

Comment: at the moment, rockstar, you've not added your code into your question. It's currently in comments outside of your question.